Can't expose Airflow UI with Classic Load Balancer
I have an airflow helm release running on EKS cluster
    NAME                                     READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   LABELS
pod/airflow-postgresql-0                 1/1     Running   0          59m   app.kubernetes.io/component=primary,app.kubernetes.io/instance=airflow,app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm,app.kubernetes.io/name=postgresql,app.kubernetes.io/version=16.1.0,apps.kubernetes.io/pod-index=0,controller-revision-hash=airflow-postgresql-59f5bcc96d,helm.sh/chart=postgresql-13.2.24,statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name=airflow-postgresql-0
pod/airflow-redis-0                      1/1     Running   0          59m   apps.kubernetes.io/pod-index=0,component=redis,controller-revision-hash=airflow-redis-5fd5d95c95,release=airflow,statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name=airflow-redis-0,tier=airflow
pod/airflow-scheduler-7fbb64bf55-svssq   2/2     Running   0          59m   component=scheduler,pod-template-hash=7fbb64bf55,release=airflow,tier=airflow
pod/airflow-statsd-6df8564664-tq6dm      1/1     Running   0          59m   component=statsd,pod-template-hash=6df8564664,release=airflow,tier=airflow
pod/airflow-triggerer-0                  2/2     Running   0          59m   apps.kubernetes.io/pod-index=0,component=triggerer,controller-revision-hash=airflow-triggerer-d48d9dc45,release=airflow,statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name=airflow-triggerer-0,tier=airflow
pod/airflow-webserver-69cb8b99f-rzckw    1/1     Running   0          59m   component=webserver,pod-template-hash=69cb8b99f,release=airflow,tier=airflow
pod/airflow-worker-0                     2/2     Running   0          59m   apps.kubernetes.io/pod-index=0,component=worker,controller-revision-hash=airflow-worker-5b7cf8dc95,release=airflow,statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name=airflow-worker-0,tier=airflow

NAME                            TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP                                                                    PORT(S)             AGE     LABELS
service/airflow-postgresql      ClusterIP      172.20.217.39    <none>                                                                         5432/TCP            59m     app.kubernetes.io/component=primary,app.kubernetes.io/instance=airflow,app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm,app.kubernetes.io/name=postgresql,app.kubernetes.io/version=16.1.0,helm.sh/chart=postgresql-13.2.24
service/airflow-postgresql-hl   ClusterIP      None             <none>                                                                         5432/TCP            59m     app.kubernetes.io/component=primary,app.kubernetes.io/instance=airflow,app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm,app.kubernetes.io/name=postgresql,app.kubernetes.io/version=16.1.0,helm.sh/chart=postgresql-13.2.24
service/airflow-redis           ClusterIP      172.20.34.228    <none>                                                                         6379/TCP            59m     app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm,chart=airflow-1.14.0,component=redis,heritage=Helm,release=airflow,tier=airflow
service/airflow-statsd          ClusterIP      172.20.151.122   <none>                                                                         9125/UDP,9102/TCP   59m     app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm,chart=airflow-1.14.0,component=statsd,heritage=Helm,release=airflow,tier=airflow
service/airflow-triggerer       ClusterIP      None             <none>                                                                         8794/TCP            59m     app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm,chart=airflow-1.14.0,component=triggerer,heritage=Helm,release=airflow,tier=airflow
service/airflow-webserver       ClusterIP      172.20.102.46    <none>                                                                         8080/TCP            59m     app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm,chart=airflow-1.14.0,component=webserver,heritage=Helm,release=airflow,tier=airflow
service/airflow-webserver-lb    LoadBalancer   172.20.232.116   k8s-airflow-airfloww-694e110db8-9eaf02ffddc81713.elb.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com   80:31185/TCP        7m43s   component=webserver,release=airflow
service/airflow-worker          ClusterIP      None             <none>                                                                         8793/TCP            59m     app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm,chart=airflow-1.14.0,component=worker,heritage=Helm,release=airflow,tier=airflow

NAME                                READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE   LABELS
deployment.apps/airflow-scheduler   1/1     1            1           59m   app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm,chart=airflow-1.14.0,component=scheduler,executor=CeleryExecutor,heritage=Helm,release=airflow,tier=airflow
deployment.apps/airflow-statsd      1/1     1            1           59m   app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm,chart=airflow-1.14.0,component=statsd,heritage=Helm,release=airflow,tier=airflow
deployment.apps/airflow-webserver   1/1     1            1           59m   app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm,chart=airflow-1.14.0,component=webserver,heritage=Helm,release=airflow,tier=airflow

NAME                                           DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE   LABELS
replicaset.apps/airflow-scheduler-7fbb64bf55   1         1         1       59m   component=scheduler,pod-template-hash=7fbb64bf55,release=airflow,tier=airflow
replicaset.apps/airflow-statsd-6df8564664      1         1         1       59m   component=statsd,pod-template-hash=6df8564664,release=airflow,tier=airflow
replicaset.apps/airflow-webserver-69cb8b99f    1         1         1       59m   component=webserver,pod-template-hash=69cb8b99f,release=airflow,tier=airflow

NAME                                  READY   AGE   LABELS
statefulset.apps/airflow-postgresql   1/1     59m   app.kubernetes.io/component=primary,app.kubernetes.io/instance=airflow,app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm,app.kubernetes.io/name=postgresql,app.kubernetes.io/version=16.1.0,helm.sh/chart=postgresql-13.2.24
statefulset.apps/airflow-redis        1/1     59m   app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm,chart=airflow-1.14.0,component=redis,heritage=Helm,release=airflow,tier=airflow
statefulset.apps/airflow-triggerer    1/1     59m   app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm,chart=airflow-1.14.0,component=triggerer,heritage=Helm,release=airflow,tier=airflow
statefulset.apps/airflow-worker       1/1     59m   app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm,chart=airflow-1.14.0,component=worker,heritage=Helm,release=airflow,tier=airflow

I'm trying to expose the webserver with the following LoadBalancer Service
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: airflow-webserver-lb
  namespace: airflow
  labels:
    release: airflow
    component: webserver
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-subnets: subnet-04fdde0fa39e75951,subnet-043ffb9be25ec2ea7,subnet-0ab770df112e5e70b
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    component: webserver
    release: airflow
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8080

Selector points to the labels present on the webserver pod.
Subnet tags are correctly setup because I can see a Load Balancer being created in the console, but trying to access the UI via endpoint does the timeout.
I checked security groups and seems like CLB automatically created HTTP inbound rule accessible for anyone. I also added 8080 rule just in case, but no luck.
Any help would be appreciated.

In the Apache Airflow Helm Chart the template for webserver service is:
  selector:
    tier: airflow
    component: webserver
    release: {{ .Release.Name }}

Try adding the label tier: airflow in the your service selector.

Unfortunately, didn't help. Indeed, it's one of the labels, but the others I mention already uniquely define the service.

If you run the command 'kubectl describe svc airflow-webserver-lb' do you confirm that you display the pod's ip as an endpoint?
